# Camel InterceptFrom behavior

Tags: apache-camel

A route which polls for files has an interceptor written as below. We wanted to know the total time processed. So we logged the startTime in header.
We observed that the startTime never changes. This code is inside a RouteBuilder::configure method. I then moved the code to a bean and call the bean from the interceptor. Wanted a bit more clarity, reading the camel documenation on the interceptor, I am still not clear, why this does not work

```
 interceptFrom()
                .setHeader("fileName",
                        regexReplaceAll(simple("${file:onlyname.noext.single}"),
                                "[^a-zA-z\\d]", ""))
                .setHeader("startTime", constant(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

Comment: You already the the state time stored on the exchange as a property, you can find it there: http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.21.0/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#CREATED_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2):

Because this header is a `constant` that is set when the route is "constructed" and it never changes during runtime. So it stays the same constant value for every message processed.

See the [Camel docs for constant](http://camel.apache.org/constant.html). You can't set dynamic values with it.

But @claus-ibsen added a comment that there is already a message header with the creation timestamp of the exchange. You can just use it.

`simple("${in.header.CamelCreatedTimestamp}")`

Comment: I understood that. I was expecting the setHeader to be executed everytime a file arrived. InterceptFrom is for intercepting any incoming Exchange, in any route (it intercepts all the from DSLs) it behaved the same way with a simple expression too. in this case, for the startTime expression, there is nothing dynamic about it. the SetHeader requires an expression. You can use a constant or simple.

Comment: I added a logger after setheader. The log was printed for every file. But in the log i saw, the startTime header never changed. So from what, I understood, the header was set once in the configure method. But any log and processor or to would be executed for every incoming file

Comment: You have to make a difference between command and value. `setHeader` is a command and is obviously executed for every message processed by the route. `constant(whatever)` on the other hand is a constant value that is evaluated only once (on route building) and re-applied for every message processed.

Comment: ok. so how could we get this to work then? simple(whatever) i tried that too. it did not work

Comment: did you see my updated answer? there is already a header with the "start time" (creation of the Exchange).